# a:visited and a:hover css are not rendering correctly in Outlook or Gmail

Tags: javascript, html, css, gmail, html-email

In the email code, the `a:visited` and `a:hover` CSS style is not rendering/Working correctly in Outlook or Gmail email clients. I have added the CSS code like the following.

```
  /* unvisited link */
    a:link {
        color: #526175;
    }

    /* visited link */
    a:visited {
        color: #D4B038 !important;
    }

    /* mouse over link */
    a:hover {
        color: #D4B038 !important;
    }

    /* selected link */
    a:active {
        color: #D4B038 !important;
    }

    .menutxt a:visited {
        color: #D4B038 !important;
    }

    .menutxt a:hover {
        color: #D4B038 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about correct. Email clients do not support everything.

There are many versions of Outlook and Gmail though, and some do work, according to caniemail.

`:visited` doesn't have much support: https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=%3Avisited

`:hover` won't work on Outlook desktop, but should work on Gmail desktop/webmail: https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=%3Ahover

I suspect what is happening is that you have other things in your `<style>` that Gmail doesn't like, and what it then does is *removes the entire `<style>...</style>`* section! So, to isolate this, use the following:

```
<style>
a:link {
        color: #526175;
    }
a:hover
...
</style>
```

And let your other styles go in another `<style>` part. This isolates them so the first `<style>` section won't get removed if there's an error or unsupported style.